# Distributivity property of summations when index is equal among summations

Tags: summation

I Know that this equivalence is true, considering the distributivity property of summation:

$$\sum \limits_{i=1}^{N}x_i g_{i,l}\sum \limits_{j=1}^{N}x_j g_{j,k}=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{N}\sum \limits_{j=1}^{N}x_{i}x_{j}g_{i,l}g_{j,k}$$

I was wondering whether there are other properties that would allow me to separate $x_{i}x_{j}$ from $g_{i,l}g_{j,k}$.

Comment: I made a correction on the question. Any thoughts on this?